# Cannot 'push' to array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to push an element to the end of this array and I get an error I don't understand.

main.rb:

```
require 'shop.rb'
so = Shop.new()
so.get(2)
so.get(1)
```

shop.rb

```
class Shop

    def new()
       @products = []
    end


    def get(product)
       @products.push(product)
    end
end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: This question and answers would be more helpful to others if you kept your original code snippet. No need to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, the constructor is `initialize`, not `new`. But you still use `new` to create an object, e.g. `Checkout.new`.

Also, the parentheses after method names are optional, and generally avoided in Ruby when there are no arguments.

```
def initialize
  @items = []
end
```

Comment: I now get NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for Checkout:Class

Comment: Try `co = Checkout.new`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer once I'm allowed to.

Comment: Keep in mind that the class method name is `new` and the instance initializer is called `initialize`. They are not the same thing at all, but they are related.